# ogg audio file is not played by pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sdl

I have the next version of pygame package: pygame `2.5.0` (SDL `2.28.0`) in python `3.10.8`.

.ogg file generated by telegram client and uploaded to server is successfully played by VLS application but next python code

```
import pygame

audio_file_path = r'<OGG PATH>'
pygame.mixer.init()

try:
    pygame.mixer.music.load(audio_file_path)

except pygame.error as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```

brings the next error:

```
Error: stb_vorbis_open_rwops: VORBIS_invalid_first_page
```

What may be the error reason and what are additional tools that may allow me to check ogg file validity?

Comment: Could you please provide the `.ogg` file that's causing the error? I tried recreating it, but to no avail.

Comment: @KārlisKazāks, 
Here is a sample ogg file: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f_KZw0kJ8OxfiPjLUfcOQfDVyLcGDa5-/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing your code with my own `.ogg` file no errors occured. So this might just be happening to this one file. I can't tell you a reason why this happens, but i can tell you the solutions i found.

> Both solutions require downloading a module called [pydub](https://pydub.com/)

---

### Solution 1

```
import pygame
from pydub import AudioSegment
from io import BytesIO

def convert_ogg_to_mp3_object(ogg_path):
    # Load the OGG file
    ogg_audio = AudioSegment.from_ogg(ogg_path)

    # Export the OGG audio as MP3 and return the BytesIO object
    mp3_object = BytesIO()
    ogg_audio.export(mp3_object, format="mp3")

    return mp3_object

audio_file_path = r'<OGG PATH>'

file_obj = convert_ogg_to_mp3_object(audio_file_path)
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(file_obj, "")
```

Here we convert the `*.ogg` file to an mp3 file object and lucky for us pygame accepts file objects as seen [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load).

---

### Solution 2

This solution creates a mp3 file in your system rather than storing a file object.

```
import pygame
from pydub import AudioSegment

def convert_ogg_to_mp3(ogg_path, mp3_path):
    # Load the OGG file
    ogg_audio = AudioSegment.from_ogg(ogg_path)

    # Export the OGG file as MP3 to the specified path
    ogg_audio.export(mp3_path, format="mp3")

audio_file_path = r'<OGG PATH>'
output_file = "<OUTPUT PATH>"

convert_ogg_to_mp3(audio_file_path, output_file)
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("out.mp3", "mp3")
```

---

Both solutions work, but the first solution runs just a bit faster than the second. So if you are looking for performance i would suggest the first solution.

If there's a need to convert other files to `.mp3` or back to `.ogg` [pydub](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load) can do it.

Comment: In spite pydub is installed in runtime it produce next error:

lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work

Comment: @BaruchLi refer to [this](https://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/)